# Is it possible to create a gate in Q# that is dictated by a matrix?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, circuit-construction, q#

When observing the Hadamard gate it is simply a transformation matrix. I am wondering if there is functionality to hard code an arbitrary transformation matrix and its family members up till $m \times n$ size depending on the limitations of the simulation. From here I would like the hard coded gate to transform my register of qubits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently an Issue ([#291](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/issues/291)) raised on the *Microsoft QuantumLibraries GitHub* regarding an operation called `ApplyUnitaryOperation(unitary: Complex[][], qubits : LittleEndian)` which aims to do what you are asking. This functionality doesn't exist right now but it was also discussed on the [Q# Community Gitter](https://gitter.im/qsharp-community/community) a while ago. Hopefully it will be added as a feature in the future.